# Woocommerce API. Create product images

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am making a small application to upload products to Woocommerce through its api, but I have been stuck sending the images.

I am generating it with the following code (It is not complete, I have taken the extract of the function that generates the image array, and as I show it in the main process):

```
function carga_imagenes($sku){
$db=conectaBBDD();

$query = "SELECT MAX(`ancho`),`Sku`,`imagenId`,`url` FROM `imagenes_productos` WHERE `Sku`='".$sku."' GROUP by `imagenes_productos`.`imagenId`";
$sql_response = $db->query($query);
$rows = $sql_response->fetchAll();
$imagenes = array();
foreach($rows as $key => $val) 
{
    $imagenes['images'] = array('src'=>$val['url']);
} 

return(json_encode($imagenes));
```

}

Where I generate the code to send to Woocommerce, and call the function to generate images:

```
 $item_data = [
        'name' => $search_item['Description'],
        'type' => 'simple',
        'regular_price' => strval($search_item['precio']),
        'stock_quantity' => strval($search_item['stock']),
        'sku' => $search_item['sku'],
        'description' => $search_item['Description'],
        'weight' => $search_item['peso'],
        carga_imagenes($search_item['sku'])
        ];
```

I am not using Curl but the Woocommerce library itself. I have the problem when generating the content that I send, all the fields (name, price, weight) load them well ... except the images ... and I think it is because I am not applying the format well, But I do not know how to do it.

The output that is being generated with this code is:

```
Array(
[name] => Microsoft Compact Optical Mouse for Business - Ratón - diestro y zurdo - óptico - 3 botones - cableado - USB
[type] => simple
[regular_price] => 0
[stock_quantity] => 0
[sku] => 4HH-00001
[description] => Microsoft Compact Optical Mouse for Business - Ratón - diestro y zurdo - óptico - 3 botones - cableado - USB
[weight] => 0
[0] => {"images":{"src":"https:\/\/iwsportaldvlp.intcomex.com\/images\/1373180948"}})
```

It does not give me an error but it does not load the images ... I suppose that due to a format error

Comment: If you are working with woocommerce api - than I believe the data should be sent as json... what is your post code? are you curling the post correctly and sending the data as json??  show your json and your curl.

Answer (score 1):

Your post code should contain json and will work like this:
(I chose a product sku as an example you should use the one u need) - url is just an example....

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://wp.yourwebsite.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/13062?consumer_key=secret_key&consumer_secret=consumer_secret&_method=PUT',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
    "images": [
        {
            "src": "http:\\/\\/demo.woothemes.com\\/woocommerce\\/wp-content\\/uploads\\/sites\\/56\\/2013\\/06\\/T_2_front.jpg"
        },
        {
            "src": "http:\\/\\/demo.woothemes.com\\/woocommerce\\/wp-content\\/uploads\\/sites\\/56\\/2013\\/06\\/T_2_back.jpg"
        }
    ]
}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

It is enough to send just the image portion of the json - no need for all the  rest...

in json your images array looks like:

```
{
    "images": [
        {
            "src": "http:\/\/demo.woothemes.com\/woocommerce\/wp-content\/uploads\/sites\/56\/2013\/06\/T_2_front.jpg"
        },
        {
            "src": "http:\/\/demo.woothemes.com\/woocommerce\/wp-content\/uploads\/sites\/56\/2013\/06\/T_2_back.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is how you update/add product images to product via Woocommerce API.